# Input mask for min:sec when persisted to database, save as seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I have a form that has one of the fields masked like this :

```
   <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
    <label class="control-label">Km </label>
   <input class="form-control  input-lg time" name="km" type="text" 
    placeholder="__ min : __ sec" /> 
    </div>
```

And the JS function :

```
 $(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".time").mask("99 min : 99 sec", {
            placeholder: "__ min : __sec"
        });
    });
```

When persisting this to the database, It is used as String and it shows : 55min:5sec as a string

What I want to be able to do is , after submitting the form, the input in that field to be converted to seconds and saved to Database as a number
How do I do this ?
I am using Spring Java for backend. So all database columns are in an Entity

And I save the form calling the .save() function from the repository for that object.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest would be to do this in javascript, but then you can't do this in a plain html form. A HTML form is like WYSIWYG, you can't really have fancy logic in it. You could push this concern into your java spring app but then you pollute the code with UI concerns which is not good. Better to do away with the traditional form. You can still have a form component, just instead of having a submit button use a button with a javascript callback and handle this stuff yourself.

These days you pretty much need to pick up react or angular for front end, vanilla javascript and HTML just doesn't cut it as you are finding yourself. I don't recommend you use templating libraries rather develop a front end app separately and create REST APIs for your spring app which can be called by your front end javascript app, but can later also be used by your ios or android app or whichever you see? These are best practices these days.